# Проблема с регулярным выражением C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть выражение `"\"" + ".*?[^\\]" + "\""`. Оно прекрасно работает на regex101.com, но при компиляции в VS происходит ошибка, что не закрыт набор символов `[]`. Он не закрывается из-за того, что перед `]` идет `\`. И я не знаю как это исправить. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде `"[^\\]"` представляет собой текст `[^\]`, который не является правильным символьным классом, так как заключительная скобка экранирована, а соответственно символьный класс не закрыт, как следует.

Вообще-то, это неправильное выражение для поиска текста между двойными кавычками, между которыми могут находиться escape-последовательности.

Не забывайте использовать 4 символа обратной косой черты в регулярных выражениях, заданных обычными строковыми литералами, для поиска символа `\` (и тогда нужно экранировать двойные кавычки символом `\`) (т.е. строковой литерал `"\"\\\\"` представляет собой текст `"\\`), и 2 символа `\` в "verbatim" строковых литералах (экранируя двойные кавычки ещё одной двойной кавычкой (т.е. `@"""\\"` = `"\\`).

Используйте

```
var rx = new Regex(@"""[^\\""]*(?:\\.[^\\""]*)*""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Ещё лучше,

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)""[^\\""]*(?:\\.[^\\""]*)*""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%7B2%7D%29*%29%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*%28%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*%29*%22&i=Some%20%22text%22%0D%0ASome%20%22%5C%22more%5C%22%20text%22%0D%0ASome%20%22%5C%22more%5Cr%5Cn%20text%5C%22%22%0D%0A).

[Пример задания шаблонов с помощью двух разных типов литералов на C#](https://ideone.com/DBGBXg):

```
Console.WriteLine(@"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)""[^\\""]*(?:\\.[^\\""]*)*""");
Console.WriteLine("(?<=(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*)\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"");
// => (?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"
```